# Why I receive wrong chunk size after setting setChunkedStreamingMode?

Tags: java, android, sockets

On client side ( Android ) I sent a file using following code:

```
public String sendFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl) {
        String response = "error";
        Log.e("Image filename", filename);
        Log.e("url", targetUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = filename;
        String urlServer = targetUrl;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss");

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            //connection.set
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            String connstr = null;
            connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + "uploadedfile.log" + "\"" + lineEnd;
            Log.i("Connstr", connstr);

            outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.e("Image length", bytesAvailable + "");
            try {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        response = "outofmemoryerror";
                        return response;
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "error";
                return response;
            }
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("Server Response Code ", "" + serverResponseCode);
            Log.i("Server Response Message", serverResponseMessage);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                response = "true";
            }

            String CDate = null;
            Date serverTime = new Date(connection.getDate());
            try {
                CDate = df.format(serverTime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Date Exception", e.getMessage() + " Parse Exception");
            }
            Log.i("Server Response Time", CDate + "");

            filename = CDate
                    + filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."),
                    filename.length());
            Log.i("File Name in Server : ", filename);

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            response = "error";
            Log.e("Send file Exception", ex.getMessage() + "");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

On server side, I implemented a simple SocketServer using Java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
        ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(8081);
            while(true){

        Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("Just connected to "+ socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

        BufferedInputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        int x;
        while((x=in.read())!=-1){
           System.out.print((char)x);
        }

            }

        }catch(IOException e){

        }

    }
}
```

I was trying to check what exactly is being sent from Android side. To my surprise, I surely receive chunked data but the chunk header contains wrong chunk size. Content size of what follows after chunk size is different from chunk size mentioned.

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There's some information on HttpURLConnection documentation - _chunkLength_ may be treated as a hint only - and actual chunk size may vary.

Comment: Yeah, it may surely vary but it has to be equal to the content size it follows.  It can be different from what chunk size you requested though.